# solution in functional equations

Tags: functions

> Let $f(x)$ be a twice-differentiable function real valued function satisfying the equation $$ x + f(x)\, f'(x) + f'(x)\, f''(x) = 0,$$ then, $$ \begin{array}{cr}\text{(A)} & \displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} x\, f(x) = -1 \\ \text{(B)} & \displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} \dfrac{f'(x)}{\ln |x|} = 0 \\ \text{(C)} & \displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}  x\, f(x)\, f'(x) = 1\\ \text{(D)} & \displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} \dfrac{f(x)\, f'(x)}{\ln |x|} = 0 \end{array} $$

I have tried combining with multiplying by
$e^x$, but not able to combine it.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: You're a member for quite a lot time here you should try to learn at least some [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). About the question this is equivalent to $(x^2+f(x)^2+f'(x)^2)'=0$ hence $x^2+f(x)^2+f'(x)^2$ is constant. Not sure if that helps though.

Comment: i can only say since f is differentiable, so at each point f’ finite, so in option B numerator is finite, but denom is infinite so limit is zero. is this correct?